# food safety regarding re freezing twice cooked chicken

Tags: food-safety

I am defrosting a cooked chicken to use in a curry it will be thoroughly heated at a high temperature. If I have too much curry will i be able to freeze it, as the cooked chicken was frozen before?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you treat the food safely in between, and the communicative time in the danger zone of 40-140 F / 4 - 60 C does not exceed about 2 hours, you can thaw and refreeze foods an unlimited number of times.  Whether they are raw or cooked doesn't matte *for safety*.

On the other hand, multiple thawing and refreezing may degrade the quality of the food, especially its texture, and is generally avoided for that reason.

Thawing cooked chicken once, cooking in a curry, then freezing the cooked product is probably well within the tolerances of most people's palette, and you probably will not notice any quality loss, especially in an application like curry.  Just don't over cook your chicken--that will definitely result in dry, tough chicken and won't be pleasant.